# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp

I am trying to call and retrieve images from my web service so that I can display it on my website.

Everything is working well in POSTMAN (chrome extension)

But when I do this in jquery..

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://mywebservices...blahblah',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
        var content = ' ';
        for(var i=0; i<response.images.length;i++) {
            if(response.status == 0) {
                content = content + '<div class="animated slideInLeft">' + '<img src="' + result.images[i].s3File.url +'">' + '<div>';
            }
        }

        $( ".aboutus-slider" ).HTML(content);
    }
});
```

Is there any other ways I can do to easily retrieve the images so that I can display in my website? I have been working on this for the whole day..

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript